# Thunderbird: Keeps asking me to add security exception

Tags: email, certificate, thunderbird

I've been using Thunderbird for ages without any (real) problems. A few days ago, Thunderbird updated to version 78.5.0. Shortly thereafter the problems started. I can't remember if it started immediately after the update so I'm not sure if the update was the direct cause.

Anyway, every time I try to retrieve my mail (by clicking "Get Messages") a pop-up appears:

[image: Security Pop-Up Thunderbird]

This pop-up isn't new to me since I'm using my own mail server with a self-signed certificate. So every time I update the certificate, I get this popup. It *is* new however the pop-up appears while nothing has changed (other than Thunderbird updating).

If I click "Confirm Security Exception", the popup disappears but no mail is retrieved. If I click "Get Messages" again, the pop-up reappears. Oddly enough, If I go to Thunderbird's Certificate Manager, I see the certificate was actually added.

So that's one strange thing. It isn't the strangest thing however. What's even stranger is that the location (email.glasshouse.nl:995) isn't the address of my mail server. If I look under Thunderbird's "Server Settings", I see the correct address. Even if I change the server address to something else (the IP address for instance), the pop-up still displays **email.glasshouse.nl** as location. I'm not worried this is some kind of hack or virus or malware since I recognize the address - it's the mail server I used well over ten years ago (in Thunderbird).

So what is actually going on here? And more important, how can I solve this so I can get to my email again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be a valid problem. I've got exactly the same problem, including that the location displayed isn't the address of the mail server, it is a old one which expired for a few years.

Comment: Looks like bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1681489

Comment: This issue is only getting worse, the thunderbird (which i've used ever since) now asks me to answer this same popup twice in succession. Last straw for me, can anyone recommend similar feel free email client?

Answer (score 0):

Had some time this morning and did a bit of digging.

There is a cert_override.txt file in your thunderbird profiles directory, stop thunderbird, open it and change the wrong/invalid hostname to the correct one, save and start thunderbird.

Comment: For me, this only works until the next Windows reboot. Then the old (changed) line in cert_override.txt needs to be deleted, Thunderbird restarted and the invalid hostname changed again.

Comment: Btw, you mean "kill" thunderbird, not "stop" thunderbird. Stopping it does not work. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

On the file itself it says:

> # This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

So editing it may not help!

My problem is really similar, every time i reboot Windows 10, Thunderbird asks again for adding the exception; please note that i had also verified at ThunderBird start that the exception it will add is already present there, so after the window where you tell it to store it permanently nothing is changed in the configuration of certificates exceptions.

I my case is Avast the one that cause the problem, since deactivating eMail scan the problem does not show until i reactivate Avast mail shield.

The weird thing id that in old versions of Thunderbird / Avast / Windows 10 that problem (re-ask for exception after windows reboot) never appeared.

Hope a fix is found soon, it is getting mad a lot of people.

Comment: And the thunderbird devs keep closing the bugs opened to report this without fixing it. By the way, this bug *has* existed for years. At least for me it has, across several versions of tbird